# How is sun's atmosphere (corona) hotter than the surface itself?

Tags: thermodynamics, sun, solar-system

Through some research online, I found out that the sun's corona is hotter than it's surface. How's that even possible?? Is the sun releasing it's heat from the surface!!! Need a complete answer.

Comment: This link has some clues, but not a complete answer. http://discovermagazine.com/2013/september/06-understanding-suns-energy

Comment: Keep in mind that "temperature" and "heat" are separate things. The corona is very rarified compared to the surface; it may have a higher temperature, but I doubt it has a higher energy.

Comment: What @Asher said. The corona's specific heat is probably very low. Water at 180F is considerably "hotter" (and more dangerous) than air at 180F, because water has a much higher specific heat.

Comment: @barrycarter that doesn't explain how heat flows from 6000k surface to several million K corona

Comment: You found it from your own research?  What instruments did you use and how?